# Revenuecat, Flutter - PurchasePackage does not work, but there are no exceptions

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

Here is the scenario:

1. Sandbox user bought a subscription and it expired.
2. Sandbox user tries to buy that same subscription again.

Apple's IAP UX is not triggered, and the PurchaserInfo object comes back with out a new purchase and the new entitlement. There are no exceptions thrown.

Inside the Purchaser Info object, I see the old entitlements and expired subscriptions.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I'm having this same problem and I'm using the latest version of the plugin and flutter. Getting no help on RCs github page.

Answer (score 1):

For the ones who're getting `PurchasesErrorCode.operationAlreadyInProgressError`:

There is a bug in `purchases-flutter` <= 1.2.1, that's been fixed in 1.3.0 and later. The bug itself is caused by a race condition and reproducible if you begin a purchase *within* the completion block of a previous purchase, for example if you have a retry mechanism in the error callback.

More details here: https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-ios/pull/313

The solution would be to upgrade, I'd recommend updating to the latest version available (currently 1.4.3).

If you're already using `purchases-flutter` >= 1.3.0, you should reach out to RevenueCat support at http://support.revenuecat.com so that they can help further.

Comment: The problem is not getting operationAlreadyInProgressError. the call gets stuck with no error

Comment: You should always try to set up the SDK as early as possible in your app flow. This is so that the SDK catches transactions in the queue as soon as they happen, which may include transactions happening outside of your app (like from the iOS setting menu).
In addition, you should only ever need to call `setup` exactly once, there's no need to ever call it again. If a user logs out, you can use `reset` to reset the SDK to use a new anonymous ID, but you shouldn't call `setup` more than once in your app.

Comment: As I explained below, there is a plugin conflict between AudioService and RevenueCat. Normally, e.g. in the sample app, everything works fine as you explained. But in my case after playing audio, RevenueCat calls got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue, for different scenarios.
Sometimes the "purchasePackage" method succeeds, sometimes it doesn't return. no exception is thrown, the product's bottomsheet is not shown. If the purchase button is tapped again, I will get `PurchasesErrorCode.operationAlreadyInProgressError`. It's happening for sandbox and normal users.

In the logs I see `purchase started`, nothing more.

Comment: Yep. Exact same issue.

Comment: May I ask you which plugins are you using? It could be a conflict between plugins. 
I had the same issue for the `identify` method, as a plugin conflict. I fixed it with a timeout.

Comment: I use a ton of plugins! But also, for me it works 90% of the time without a hitch (and I also submitted to the app store and the app was approved). But once in a while, I hit this error.

Comment: The problem is the money that we may lose! It's very critical for me

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after a week of investigating the issue, I found the issue and a workaround: The problem is a conflict between AudioService and RevenueCat Purchase plugins. Calling "Purchases.setup" method in "initState" solved the issue.

Comment: Do you mean we should call Purchases.setup() right before calling Purchases.purchasePackage()? I call Purchases.setup() on main() but the issue still exists

Comment: If you are facing this plugin conflict, you need to re-setup Purchases before getting purchase info and getting offerings (most probably in initState method).